# Autofill OTP verification code in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can i change the TextView property content-type to oneTimeCode so that i can get otp in the suggestion of app.
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view

Comment: consider including what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try setting it on the native view as demonstrated in the [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6686#issue-389024709)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use @kefah/nativescript-otp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).